Force intermediate cert update in IIS
HTTPS website under IIS. The site certificate is signed by a public authority. The intermediate certificate got updated by the issuing company with the same key. The old, expired one was stored on the server and IIS would serve it up (making for an effectively invalid trust chain). The updated intermediate cert is available via the CA Issuer URL in the Authority Information Access (AIA) extension of the site certificate, but not every HTTPS client out there does AIA chasing. Chrome and Schannel do, but OpenSSL and Python's urllib3 don't.
I've resolved it in a rather roundabout way. I've downloaded and installed the updated intermediate cert, deleted the old one from the store, then deleted and recreated the HTTPS binding on the site in IIS. Question, is there an easier way? Simply installing the new cert in the machine store/intermediate didn't work.
